# Send from Gmail with another email address as the Reply-to or From address

Tags: gmail

I have a domain registered, but it isn't attached to a hosting package or e-mail account. I will do soon, but not at the moment. Right now, I would like to set up an e-mail forwarding scenario. So, I could have the email me@example.com forward to my@gmail.com. I know this much is possible.

I would like the Gmail account to keep the forwarded e-mail address when replying. So when I reply to emails sent to Gmail through my e-mail forwarding, I would like any reply to say it came from me@example.com instead of my@gmail.com.

How would I go about it?

Comment: For anyone just getting into this question, look at: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72975/279655. It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, and it's pretty easy too:

1. Go to Gmail settings
2. Go to Accounts and Import Tab
3. Click on Send Mail from another address
4. Enter the Forward account address.
5. The email should send to that address which should forward back to your Gmail.
6. Complete the steps in the email.

When you send a new email you can now change the from address to your forward account.

Comment: Google doesn't seem to use this method anymore. Now you need a mailbox to authenticate with.

Comment: Strangely, their documentation in https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?visit_id=637654312620171170-1165085619&hl=en&rd=1 implies that the “Send Verification” step is available. Also, as @pgarciacamou pointed out - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66228/add-new-alias-to-gmail-without-smtp-forwarding-only-address/72975#72975

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I have a very similar domain setup to you, just a dumping ground for me but I've setup gmail to pull down any mail that is sent to me@domain.com via POP3. This added a drop down at the top of any new gmail that allows me to choose a send as address, either me@gmail.com or me@domain.com.

So perhaps rather than forwarding from domain.com set Gmail to pull from that address and you'll be away.

Comment: I will give this some thought, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This approach no longer works:  Google requires the "send from" email address to receive a verification code which is then entered before the the Google setup can complete.

Comment: @mickburkejnr I guess you have already went to setup email forwarding for your me@example.com email, under "example.com" domain name. Your domain registrar should have allowed you to use email forwarding. As fas as for the scenario in which you'd pull down any email sent to me@example.com, using POP3, you'd need to setup POP3 for me@example.com, first.