# Add new alias to Gmail without SMTP (forwarding-only address)

Tags: gmail

I used to be able to go to *Accounts and Import* → *Add another email address you own* and add an email account that's only a forwarding address. That is, it's not a mailbox and I don't have SMTP access to it.

Gmail would send me a confirmation email to that address, I'd confirm it's mine, and done. Now it only gives me the option to add SMTP credentials.

Did they stop supporting the previous method? Is there any other way I can get that option back?

Comment: The interesting part is that they still don't support separate single-purpose-only passwords for smtp at gmail.com themselves (unless you go into a separate and non-related two-factor auth), so, if this policy of theirs were to be implemented by example.su, requiring the smtp password of gmail.com, and giving access to the whole Google Account of the user, just for smtp, how would they feel?

Really bad move, Google.  Or at least they could start letting people have single-purpose-only passwords, like for outgoing mail only.

Comment: If you own the domain name of the address you are trying to add, you can use another SMTP like Amazon SES (just did it).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Gmail recently changed its policy. Now it does not permit anymore to use the Gmail SMTP server to send email on behalf of another domain. This is to avoid spammers and enforce some security policy.

So, if you have an address aaa@bbb.com you also must have an SMTP server for bbb.com (e.g. smtp.bbb.com) and an account on that SMTP server. If you have those, you can enter that information in Gmail and set up that account as an alias.

Essentially, Gmail becomes just a client for that address, using the address’ SMTP server instead of Gmail SMTP server, to send mail for that address.

You can continue to use the Gmail SMTP server to send mail only for other Gmail addresses, or for Google Apps addresses.

References:

- [Support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370), originally posted [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/GyeMcHv1U-g/OC2v0YPf2T8J)
- [Unofficial Google OS blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/08/external-addresses-no-longer-use-gmail.html)

EDIT

The method described below in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72975/60630 works for sending mail, but has a drawback: your mail **is not verified** and risks going to the SPAM. This is because Gmail uses SPF and DKIM. You could add google in your domain's SPF, but not authenticate with DKIM.

Comment: "it does not permit anymore to use the Gmail SMTP server to send email on behalf of another domain" This is not true, as explained in the below, highest rated answer (and works for me) http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72975/60630

Comment: Previous comment is true. As of 06/22/2016, i could create a new sender email using John answer.

Comment: Be aware though that if you send e-mail on behalf of another domain those will most possibly go to spam.

Comment: Worked for me 10/18/2021

Answer (score 168):

As in Kzar's answer, you now need to provide details for an SMTP server which will be used to send the mail.

As of writing, however, you **can** simply use the Gmail SMTP server, as long as you use [Google two-step authentication.](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)

So just for completeness, the full steps:

1. Gmail settings, *Accounts and Import* tab.
2. *Add another email address you own*
3. Type name and email address to be added.
4. For *SMTP Server*, put `smtp.gmail.com`
5. For *Username*, your full Gmail address including `@gmail.com`
6. For *password*, provide an App Password generated in Google Accounts at https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
7. Leave *Secured connection using TLS* selected as is.
8. *Add Account*

**Update:** I have been advised that while this process is now a bit hit-or-miss, trying these steps several (4-5) times in a row can eventually lead to success. Further feedback in comments would be appreciated.

Comment: This works as John has mentioned, with the caveat that you need to enable 2 factor and generate an app password in order to do so. Spend a while trying to get this to work without it but couldn't, enabled it, generated the key and dropped it in, and it went straight through

Comment: @RobertHundley Thank you for the confirmation Robert, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This worked for me too, and I was able to send and receive emails from & to an email address that was defined in GoDaddy to forward to my gmail account (i.e. without even creating a full smtp\pop email account with user and password on GoDaddy). @Kzar wrote "You can continue to use the Gmail SMTP server to send mail only for other Gmail addresses, or for Google Apps addresses." - Does that mean that an email from my gmail that was sent as the other account (aaa@bbb.com) to a non-gmail account, may be blocked? (since it was sent by smtp.gmail.com and not smtp.bbb.com).

Comment: P.S. this answer is really useful in the case of GoDaddy Email Forwarding - where you specify an email address (aaa@bbb.com) to be forwarded to another email address (aaa@gmail.com), and want to be able to send and receive emails as aaa@bbb.com from gmail, but don't have a user & password at smtp.bbb.com (aaa@bbb.com is not an smtp\pop account - it's just an address marked for forwarding that does not store emails or let you login as "aaa@bbb.com" to GoDaddy's smtp servers).

Comment: Awesome. Had to do this just to change my surname... BTW, I got a "Not Found 404" page when I typed the credentials and hit "Save changes". Tried again and finally worked.

Comment: This method is not working for me. Tried at 7:36PM 23 May 2016. I got this error:
Server response: 534-5.7.9 **Application-specific password required.**
Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 59sm6004998oti.32 - gsmtp code(534).
Solution: refer @harry-glinos answer

Comment: re @sky91's comment, still works for me

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Worked perfectly, even without using Google Domains (got mine from INWX). Luckily, I already had 2-factor authentication enabled. Do you know by any chance the reason why your normal gmail password wouldn't work (without 2fa)?

Comment: @Maxr1998 Sorry, I don't. My original answer didn't mention 2fa (as I have always used it and didn't realise it was necessary), and several people stated that it didn't work without it. I don't recall if I ever actually tested it. Happy to help, anyway! :)

Comment: Works beautifully!

Comment: @sky91 Looking at your comment again, this looks like you tried to use your regular password to add the email address. Make sure you're generating an app-specific password (via *step 6*) and using this.

Comment: Couldn't make it work with my Google Apps account: I was able to add the address successfully (using an app password), but instead of receiving a confirmation code, I get an email saying "553 sorry, that domain isn't allowed to be relayed thru this MTA (#5.7.1)".

Comment: Still working as of 2017-03-16

Comment: In step 3 you say "Untick treat as an alias." Why? Reading [about that feature](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25493/what-does-treat-as-an-alias-do-in-gmail), it seems better to leave it checked.

Comment: @NathanArthur Sorry, this was sufficiently long ago that I have no idea why I wrote that. If you can confirm that the process works exactly the same without unticking it, I will remove it from the answer :) EDIT: Good to see that this is helping the world's population of Nathan Arthurs (well, two and counting)

Comment: @John I don't actually need to follow the process right now, so I don't have a good way to test it. And yeah, that threw me off for a minute, too!

Comment: @John Confirmed, process is working with "Treat as an alias" left ticked. Thanks for the very useful write-up!

Comment: @ErikKoopmans Thanks! I have updated the answer to reflect this. If anyone has any difficulties please let me know.

Comment: this works ! thank you, this should be chosen as the right answer.

Comment: Anyone know how to set up SPF records and DKIM for your domain if you use this method?

Comment: @Ecksters please see (and upvote) my question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109591/9617

Comment: I hold a Gsuite account with my own domain, and the steps listed in this answer helped. My password, though, was my Gsuite login.

Comment: Still works as of 3//27/2019!

Comment: **Important:** the email account used in the `username` will be included in the email source content. Gmail adds the code `Return-Path: <yourmail@gmail.com>`, so be careful since you might end up making public your private mail address when sending mails with the alias.

Comment: Still working on 1/4/2020

Comment: This should be the Accepted answer . it works !

Comment: Not working as of October 2021. Getting "Temporary Error (404). We’re sorry, but your account is temporarily unavailable." no matter how many times I try (after following the steps above exactly).

Comment: As in the edit above, I have been advised that trying these steps several (4-5) times in a row can eventually lead to success. Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @John I can confirm that it worked on the second try on my end, so it seems this still works. As mentioned above, the Gmail email address will appear in the email headers though, so that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I edited my answer above. Please note that although this method works, your mail could go to the SPAM folder.

Comment: It doesn't work if your account is enrolled in Advanced Protection as the App Password require 2-step authentication. You will get the message: The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.

Answer (score 9):

If you are a Google Domains user, you can still add a new alias for your non-gmail domain, but you must have 2-step verification turned on.

1. Turn on 2-step verification if you haven't done so already.
2. Goto your Account -> Signing In ->  App Passwords
3. In the App passwords box, select Mail for the app, select Other for the device.
4. Enter the name of your domain for the “other” device, and click Generate.
5. Goto Gmail settings, Accounts and Import tab.
6. Click on **Add another email address you own**
7. Type name and email address to be added from a domain hosted on Google Domains. (It didn't seem to matter if **treat as an alias** was checked or not).
8. For SMTP Server, put smtp.gmail.com
9. For Username, your full Gmail address including @gmail.com
10. For password, your App password generated from step 4.
11. Leave the rest default (TLS, port 587)
12. Click **Add Account**

For more details see [Google Support - Sending mail from your forwarded email address](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en#from). The link says to use port 465, but leaving it as TLS and port 587 worked just fine for me.

Comment: You don't need to be a Google domains user. See my answer from 7 hours ago...

Comment: @John I tried your solution first and it didn't work for me. Google prevented me from signing in.

Comment: Interesting. Could it be that it's just 2-step authentication that needs to be on? I have tested this with two accounts and neither domain is on Google Domains, but both accounts do use 2-step. Will check and update.

Comment: This is confirmed to work as of June 2015. I wish to use email/alias M1 from account A1 with account A2. 1. Generate app key on A1. 2. Add email in Gmail on account A2. 3. Use smtp.gmail.com as server, M1 email as username and the generated app key as password.

Answer (score 6):

OK, there is a silver lining here.  I just set this up and it is working fine: 
You do not have to use an SMTP server that matches the domain of the email address.  You only have to use an SMTP server.  So as long as you have access to *any* SMTP server, you can set up forwarders or an unlimited number of email addresses.

Comment: Does this mean you can use one of GMail's *own* SMTP servers, and provide any valid GMail username/password?

Comment: Yep! Just about to post an answer about this

Answer (score 3):

Gmail no longer support using the Gmail outgoing mail server for Send Mail As if the account is not another Gmail or account or a Google Apps account.

You'll need to contact whoever hosts the forwarder you use and see what they can do for you.