# Gmail send from forwarding address

Tags: gmail

I have a forwarding address `foo@acm.org` that forwards to `foo@gmail.com`. I want to be able to send from my `acm.org` email, so I tried to add the email in *Settings* → *Accounts and Import*, but it didn't work since `acm.org` isn't an SMTP server—it just forwards everything it gets to my Gmail. How can I send from my `acm.org` email in Gmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72994/95015). For security reasons, Gmail requires you to provide an SMTP server for your alias email. However, they don't check that they match up. I just used `smtp.gmail.com` as the server and my Gmail username and password for the username and password and it worked.

Comment: I would be careful with this. It's a red flag for spam filters when the from address doesn't match the sending server.