# Mailing from name@example.com using Gmail, but I don't have SMTP

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, domain, smtp, alias

I own several domains where I don't have separate mailboxes or mail user accounts. To receive mail, I've just setup a catch-all for such a domain that redirects to a generic address elsewhere.

Now, I want to add myname@example.com as my address in Gmail (as an alias), so I can send mail using that as From-address. In the past I could simply add it, click a confirmation link, and done.

However, it seems that Gmail demands an SMTP server + user account for that domain!? I don't have that. And even if my domain would come with an SMTP server, I still don't have a mailbox or user account (since I only use email forwarding on that domain).

How do I setup Gmail so I can send mails from my custom mail address, which I do own, but for which I don't have an SMTP server or account?

Comment: As Vidar mentioned in his answer, this is a duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66228/add-new-alias-to-gmail-without-smtp-forwarding-only-address/

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72975/21583), but I'm unable to close it because of the bounty.

In short, you may use Gmail's SMTP server for your alias address, as long as you have enabled two-factor authentication.