# DKIM Email authentication from standard gmail?

Tags: gmail, authentication

[image]

I want to send out email from my domain, but when I do, recipients are seeing a question mark indicating that I'm [not authenticated](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?authuser=2&visit_id=1-636405600708858798-4136111782&p=email_auth&hl=en&rd=1).

It seems that [gmail only supports digitally-signed DKIM if you subscribe to G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/180504?hl=en).  Is it possible in standard gmail?

Comment: How are you sending email from your domain? Are you using the Gmail servers or do you have your own SMTP servers?

Comment: Alternate SMTP servers through go Daddy. Different domain though. Is it possible to use Gmail SMTP?

Comment: @Rubén I'm pretty sure in order to send from another email address, gmail requires you to use external SMTP servers; don't they?

Comment: @glenviewjeff they don't, see [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72975). (Okay, I realise you've now seen it already but thought worth posting here.)

Comment: I did end up switching to Gmail servers per the other question, worked fine. So my authentication is no longer needed. I'll post the "answer" later